# TabbarController badgeValue not set after logout

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uitabbar, badge

First time I am able to set badgeValue on tabbar Controller but after logout I am not able to set tabbar badgeValue, it always returns nil.

```
      let tabArray = self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.tabBar.items as NSArray!


        if(tabArray != nil)
        {
           let tabItem = tabArray.objectAtIndex(3) as! UITabBarItem
                tabItem.badgeValue = "100";
        }else
        {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let main_tabbar = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabbar") as! tabbar
            let tabArray = main_tabbar.tabBar.items as NSArray!


            if(tabArray != nil)
            {
         //...........Problem is Here ......
                let tabItem = tabArray.objectAtIndex(3) as! UITabBarItem
                tabItem.badgeValue = "100"; //Here is not Update but code working
            }else
            {
              print("Not gatting tabbar")
            }

        }
```

On Storyboard I have create TabbarController and set identify name is "tabbar" and class name is tabbar.

Here is my code On "Logout" button I am showing first page:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstNavigation")
         UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController = initialViewController
         UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: insert 

print( NSThread.isMainThread() )     

at the 

//...........Problem is Here ......  

line and let me know the result.

Comment: Where i put this line in code

Comment: Maybe anywhere in your code above.

Comment: Replacing //...........Problem is Here ......  will be nice.

Comment: Its always return me true . Please help me . i cant able to get solution

Comment: Thanks, my expectations were wrong, I cannot find the answer.